# SMTP connection test

Tags: java, smtp

I've been working on a prj(using JAVA SMTPAPI) in which I have to write a program for connectivity with SMTP. I have written a program using help of Google. now plz what I have to do? I have no IDEA further.
any advice or help would be appritiated
I have got this code

```
package mypackage;

import javax.mail.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;


public class Sendmail {

    private String strstmp;

    public String getStrstmp() {
        return strstmp;
    }


    public void setStrstmp(String strstmp) {
        this.strstmp = strstmp;
    }

    public void sendMail( String recipients[ ], String subject, String message , String from)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean debug = false;

        //set the host smtp addrs 
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host",getStrstmp());

        //get default session
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        session.setDebug(debug);

        //create a new message 
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);


        //set the from and to addrs
        InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
        msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
        InternetAddress[] addressto = new InternetAdrress[recipients.length];

        for(i = 0;i<recipients.length;i++)
        {

                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);

        }
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        // Setting the Subject and Content Type
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");

        //send message
        Transport.send(msg);

    }




}

now wat would be addrs of host? 
how to do connectivity test ?

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: You have to be more specific. What do you want to do? What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have access to a [SMTP Server](http://www.google.ro/search?q=smtp%20server). You can install one locally for tests, see search results!

Comment: K Thanks Vlad I try. Install a SMTP server on my machnine and then if it not works I'll ask u again:)